# how to get entity manager in view helper using doctrine2 zf2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Following code is working fine with AbstractPlugin but I need to access entity manager in view helper. How can I get entity manager in view helper?

Is there way to save entityManager instance somewhere in registry so that I can access it whereever i want? would that be a good practice?

```
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;


class IsAuthz extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface 
{

    /*
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */
    protected $em;
    protected $sm;    

    public function __construct($e) {
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();        
    }


    public function __invoke()
    {     
        return $this;

    }



/**
     * @return Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager() 
    {

        if (null === $this->em) {
            $this->em = $this->sm->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->em;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
     */
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em) 
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve service manager instance
     *
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public function getServiceManager() 
    {
        return $this->sm->getServiceLocator();
    }

    /**
     * Set service manager instance
     *
     * @param ServiceManager $locator
     * @return void
     */
    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager) 
    {
        $this->sm = $serviceManager;
    }



}
```

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getServiceLocator() on a non-object in XXX/XXX/src/XXX/View/Helper/IsAuthz.php on line 41
```

Comment: The error says that you haven't instantiated your ServiceManager. Perhaps that will solve your problem?

Comment: can you guide me how can I do that in viewhelper

Comment: If you need the SM in your ViewHelper, you have to inject it first. You can pass it through the View, by assigning it to the view and then assigning it to the ViewHelper inside the view (`$this->helperName()->setServiceManager($sm);` once). However, I don't think that View Helpers are supposed to perform data(base) logic. They're rather made to provide reusable snippets to change the appearance of something. If you need to know if someone is auth'd, I'd rather perform this as a controller plugin or inside any other class and pass this piece of information to the view.

Comment: To complete my above comment: The view can then take this piece of information and render whatever you want to render depending on if the user is auth'd or not.

Comment: my all ACL rules are in database, in my views I only want to show those links which are authorized and accessiable for that partical role which is logged in? Rather then checking every URL in views, is there a betterway to do this? thanks

Comment: I'd create a service class for this and pass it to the view. Using this approach, you have to pass it to each view that requires it, but you'd a. separate data logic from view logic and b. solve all your servicemanager / entitymanager issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "Daniel M" said, it is best to use the service to keep the data logic separate. but someone still want to use data logic in view helper, he can do it as below. I have changed the above code in question as follow.

```
public function __construct($e, $sm) {
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $this->sm = $sm;
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();        
    }
```

and then I inject the $sm object from module.php using

```
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
      $serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager')->setFactory('IsAuthz', function ($sm) use ($e) {
           return new \xxx\View\Helper\IsAuthz($e, $sm); 
        });
}
```

better way is to [use service in zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562538/zf2-creation-of-simple-service-and-access-it-through-viewhelper) for this purpose.