# zf2 Creation of simple service and access it through viewhelper

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I am trying to create a simple service in zf2 which I can access using in viewhelper

**Step1.** I have craeted a class in src/Application/Service/Service1.php as follow

```
namespace Application\Service;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

    class Service1 implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
    {

        public function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
        {

        }    

        public function getServiceLocator()
        {

        }

    }
```

**Step2** I set this up in module.php file as below.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{    
     return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Service\Service1' => function ($sm) {
                return new \Application\Service\Service1($sm);
            },
        )
    );   
}

public function onBootstrap($e)
{        
   $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager')->setFactory('Abc', function ($sm) use ($e) {
        return new \Application\View\Helper\Abc($sm); 
    });
}
```

**Step3** finally I am geting it in my view helper src/Application/View/Helper/Abc.php test() method like this, I I comment this line `$this->sm->get('Application\Service\Service1');` there is no error, there must be something which I am missing in service?

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

    class Abc extends AbstractHelper 
    {
       protected $sm;

       public function test()
        {
            $this->sm->get('Application\Service\Service1');
        }
        public function __construct($sm) {
            $this->sm = $sm;

        }
    }
```

**Step4** then I am calling my test view helper in one of view like this.

```
$this->Abc()->test();
```

I am getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application\Service\Service1::setView() in vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php on line 127 Call Stack:
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Please show some more (real) code. It seems like you're returning the `Service1` instance somewhere instead of `Abc`. Thus, the view helper mechanism tries to inject the view instance into the `Service1` instance.

Comment: I have changed the name and every reference from Service1 to My1serve but still getting the same error Call to undefined method My1serve::setView(). I have not used the My1serve name anywhere else in my code apart the one which i already showed in question.

Comment: Fits perfectly to the problem. We won't be able to help you without a little more information.

Comment: No problem, I have find the solution. see the answer below. thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the line `$this->sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Service\Service1');` in below method

```
class Abc extends AbstractHelper 
{
   protected $sm;

   public function test()
    {
        $this->sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Service\Service1');
    }
    public function __construct($sm) {
        $this->sm = $sm;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative, in PHP 5.4 only, without specific configuration, would be to use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

extract of module.config.php:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'myHelper' => 'Application\View\Helper\MyHelper',
    ),
```

MyHelper.php:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;  

class HeadScript extends \Zend\View\Helper\MyHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
        // do something with retrived config
    }

}
```