# ZF2 use database table model in view helper

Tags: database, model, zend-framework2, view-helpers

To show an database count in my layout.phtml I want to use the view helper to render ths count (set in an db field).

How do I use my database model in a view helper?

Helper:

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CountHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $count; 

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->count();
    }

    public function setTableCount($sm, $myCountTable)
    {
        $this->count = $sm->get($myCountTable)->getCount();
        return $this->count;        
    }
}
```

Module

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'CountHelper' => function($sm) {
                    $helper = new \Application\View\Helper\CountHelper();
                    $helper->setTableCount($sm, 'Application\Model\MyCountTable');

                    return $helper;
                },...
```

Error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Model\MyeCountTable::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway, none given, called in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 175 and defined in

Comment: Have at look at this answer from @jurian-sluiman -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175009/zf2-service-locator/14180345#14180345

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I updated my code above

Comment: In your `getViewHelperConfig()` change the `$helper->setTableCount()` line to the following, `$helper->setTableCount($sm->getServiceLocator(), 'Application\Model\MyCountTable');`

Comment: yah nice work, this worked finally and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

create a view helper

```
namespace My\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CounterHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $count;

    public function __invoke()
    {
       return $this->count;   
    }

    public function setTableCount($sm, $mytablemodel)
    {
        $this->count =  $sm->get($mytablemodel)->getCountedData();
        return $this->count;
    }
}
```

and inject view_helpers via factories

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
     'counter_helper' => function($sm) {
        $helper = new \My\View\Helper ;
            $helper->setTableCount($sm, 'mytablemodelthatalreadyregisteredinSM');

        return $helper;
     }
    )
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand the procedure but I get a error about the constructor. I updates my code above + error output. Hope you can help :) Thanks!

Comment: $helper->setTableCount($sm, 'mytablemodelthatalreadyregisteredinSM'); get not triggers