# Access Model from View Helper in Zend Framework 2

Tags: model, zend-framework2, view-helpers

i am trying to access my configured model from an custom view helper to fill in some global inputfields in my application.

Is there a way to fetch objects from that model from the view helper which i am calling from the global layout.phtml

If this is not possible, how could i pass over the values to create the elements?

Thank you alot for your help.
Jørge

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198052/zf2-use-database-table-model-in-view-helper?rq=1

Comment: ok but read my answer ... maybe it improve your app design

Answer (score 0):

there is module that allow you access to the service manager in view but its not a good way to fill out form input from model data

best way is bind the object model to the form

for more information :
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#binding-an-object